# Placing two Firestore.instances inside an initState()

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Now this maybe good practice or a complete no no!!

I was trying to resist placing more `StreamBuilder`(s) under `build(BuildContext context)` and tried to use `initState()` instead. I am having trouble due to not using `Future`/`async`/`await` correctly. The `String _leaseTenantName` (first `initState()` `Firestore.instance`) would have correct value but Strings `_leaseUnitName` & `_leaseUnitPropertyUid` (second `initState()` `Firestore.instance`) usually would return as null. `StreamBuilder<PropertyDetails>` below build would give the error message `'Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but properties has 1, null)'` but kept trying and eventually worked when `_leaseUnitPropertyUid` finally had a value.

I believe the solution is to somehow wrap the two `initState()` `Firestore.instances` in a `Future`/`async`/`await` but could not work out a way to do this. Any ideas?? Or should I just use yet more nested `StreamBuilder`s?

```dart
class _LeaseTileState extends State<LeaseTile> {
  String _leaseTenantName = '';
  String _leaseUnitPropertyUid = '';
  String _leaseUnitName = '';
  String _leasePropertyName = '';
  String _leasePropertyUnitName = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Firestore.instance
        .collection("companies")
        .document(widget.leaseDetails.tenantUid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      _leaseTenantName = snapshot.data['companyName'];
    });

    Firestore.instance
        .collection("units")
        .document(widget.leaseDetails.unitUid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) {
      _leaseUnitName = snapshot.data['unitName'];
      _leaseUnitPropertyUid = snapshot.data['propertyUid'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return StreamBuilder<PropertyDetails>(
        stream: DatabaseServices(propertyUid: _leaseUnitPropertyUid)
            .propertyByDocumentID,
        builder: (context, userCompany) {
          if (!userCompany.hasData) return Loading();
          _leasePropertyName = userCompany.data.propertyName;
          _leasePropertyUnitName = '$_leasePropertyName - $_leaseUnitName';
          return Card(
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a big no no.

Firstly, there's nothing wrong in using multiple `StreamBuilder`, `StreamBuilder` help you simplify the usage of `Streams` so you don't end up messing things up with their subscriptions... like you did in `initState()`.

When you call `listen()` on `snapshots()` as you did on `initState()`, you created a subscription, that subscription should be canceled on `dispose()`, but you don't cancel it, so you are leaking memory right there, a `StreamBuilder` would saved you here as it manages this for you.

Another thing to keep in mind is that you are using `_leaseUnitPropertyUid` on `build()`, but you don't check if `_leaseUnitPropertyUid` is valid. `_leaseUnitPropertyUid` is only going to be set after the `Firebase` `snapshot()` `Stream` emits one value and `build()` could be called before that. Again, `StreamBuilder` would have saved you here as well as you could check if it has emitted a value or not.

Also you are hardcoding the `Firebase.instance` on your code, which makes it very hard to test. Take a look on [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and try to inject the `Firebase.instance` onto your class, like a Repository pattern or something similar, so you can swap the `Firebase.instace` for a testing [Mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) and make your code more testable.